# How can I unpack a tar file into a blank disk image?

Tags: command-line, tar, disk-image

I'm trying to unpack a tar file in to a disk image which I created. I have no idea how to do it, Since the disk image `.img` is not a directory.

I have already mounted the disk image. What should I do next?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image?

Comment: if you mount the disk image with write permissions, you can unpack a tar file into mount directory, i guess something like this:
`mount -w -t iso9660 -o loop diskimage mountdir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already mounted the disk image, open a terminal and do:

```
cd /path/to/diskimage/mountpoint
tar -xvf /path/to/file.tar
```